# Can I access both cameras, wide and normal at the same time?

Tags: camera, hardware, development

Some smartphones have two cameras, working together as one implementing different parts of the zoom range.

Is it possible to use both of them at the same time?

With both at the same time, I do not necessarily mean reading the frames at the same time synchronously, reading both with 30 Hz from different threads would be great.

A problem could be if a camera needs to be initialized somehow, and only one can be in the active state at a time.

Comment: [Seems possible on some Samsung phones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075569/10193147) if you are into developing

Comment: While we might answer the technical side from the end-users perspective, take note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues.